# How to add image with Angular material?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, svg, frontend

I've tried something like that

```
            <img ng-src="~/Images/profile.svg" style="height:130px ; width:180px" class="md-card-image" alt="~/Frontend/images/question-circular-button.svg">
```

http://localhost/WebApp/~/Images/profile.svg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

The image is in that folder .. can someone please help me?

Comment: Don't use ~ in your url, and why do you use ng-src here?

Comment: @Noppey What to use?? I saw a example like that

Comment: If it's in your images directory in your /webapp, just use "/images/profile.svg". ~ is a razor / asp.net thingy to resolve roots of urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ng-src if your source is not a variable. Just use the regular html src attribute.

~ is a razor/asp.net thingy to resolve root url server side. It won't work in html code.

Just use "/Images/profile.svg".